# Finding the probability that each child gets at least 1 ball when we are distributing 5 DISTINCT balls among 4 children(who are distinct of course).

Tags: probability, combinatorics

My approach:-

First, I found the total number of cases(the sample space). We can find that out from, $$4^5=1024$$
Now for favourable cases, I did this:-

I selected any 4 balls out of the given 5 by $${5\choose 4}$$ then I gave each child 1 ball out of the selected 4 balls, that can be done in 4!  ways. With this we have provided each child 1 ball hence satisfying the condition given the question that no one should go home empty handed. Now we have 1 ball left which has to be given to any of the 4 children. So that ball can be given in 5 ways.

Hence the total favourable cases become, $${5\choose4}(4!)(5)=600$$ So the probability becomes $$600/1024$$But the answer given in the book is 15/64.

Comment: Your way of counting has many repeatitions , For example lets say you sleceted ball 1, 2,3,4 and gave it to child 1, child 2, child 3 and child 4 respectively . Then you gave the 5th ball to 1st child. Now if you select ball 5,2,3,4 and gave it to child 1,2,3 and 4 respecticely . Then you gave 1st ball to child 1. Now these 2 cases are identical but you have counted both of them .Let me know if you want to try the question yourself or you want a solution.

Comment: @aryanbansal Thanks man, that was really helpful..I am still trying on my own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’re overcounting, as described in aryan bansal’s comment. A valid method would be to use [Inclusion-Exclusion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) for counting the number of ways atleast one child gets no ball, which is $$S={4\choose 1} 3^5 -{4\choose 2} 2^5 +{4\choose 3} 1^5 $$ and then subtract this from the total ways, giving the number of ways where every child gets atleast one ball. The answer therefore is $$ \frac{4^5-S}{4^5} =\frac{15}{64}$$

Comment: We will add $${4\choose3}1^5$$ (in the sample space of course) because it got subtracted two times while we are counting for the first two cases$${4\choose 1} 3^5 -{4\choose 2} 2^5$$Am I right?

Comment: Well i think grouping method is easier tho .

Comment: And yes dravit gupta u r right

Comment: @Tavish Wait, then why did we subtract $${4\choose2}2^5?$$

Comment: @Dravit Actually, you’re right. It gets added $4$ times first, then subtracted $6$ times, then added $4$ times again giving a total of $2$ copies of it. Usually, we would want exactly one copy, so we would further subtract $${4\choose 4} 0^5$$ but it doesn’t make any difference in this case because the number of ways all children get zero balls, is zero.

Comment: @Tavish Uhh, how did $${4\choose2}2^5$$ get added 4 times, then subtracted 6 times then added 4 times?

Comment: According to me, when we write ${4\choose 1} 3^5$ we include each and every case(which are 1 child going empty handed, 2 children empty handed and 3 children empty handed) and hence we should only write  ${4\choose 1} 3^5$ in our sample space.

Comment: @Dravit Gupta I was referring to the **number of cases where $3$ children get nothing**. We first add this $4\choose 1$ times, then subtract $4\choose 2$ times, then add again $4\choose 3$ times. Also, if we only include the term you mentioned, then there is a lot of overcounting going on. For instance, we choose child $A$ and make sure he gets nothing, but then there’s also the possibility of only child $D$ getting every ball. Then one time we’re choosing child $B$ to get nothing, and $D$ to get everything. That’s a duplicate of the case already covered beforehand.

Comment: @Tavish I get why we shouldn't write only ${4\choose 1} 3^5$ in our sample space. But I still don't get why was ${4\choose2}2^5$ subtracted :( ?

Comment: @Dravit Gupta Perhaps I’m not doing a spectacular job of explaining. You may want to check the link for understanding Inclusion-Exclusion principle in detail.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110497/discussion-between-dravit-gupta-and-tavish).

Answer (score 2):

Since there are four possible recipients for each of the five balls, your denominator is correct.

As for the numerator, notice that if each child receives at least one ball, then one child must receive two of the five balls, while each of the others receives one ball.  There are four ways to select the child who will receive two balls, $\binom{5}{2}$ ways to select which two of the five balls that child will receive, and $3!$ ways to distribute the remaining three distinct balls to the other three children so that each of those children receives one ball.  Hence, the number of favorable cases is
$$\binom{4}{1}\binom{5}{2}3!$$
Therefore, the probability that each child receives at least one ball when five distinct balls are randomly distributed to four children is
$$\frac{\binom{4}{1}\binom{5}{2}3!}{4^5} = \frac{240}{1024} = \frac{15}{64}$$

*What errors did you make?*

> Now we have $1$ ball left which has to be given to any of the $4$ children. So that ball can be given in $\color{red}{5}$ ways.

There are four possible recipients for that ball, so it can only be distributed in four ways.  Had you not made that mistake, your count would have been
$$\binom{5}{4}4!4 = 480$$
which is exactly twice the number of favorable cases.

Why?

As aryan bansal pointed out in the comments, your method counts each favorable distribution twice, once for each way of designating one of the two balls the child who receives two balls as the ball that child receives and the other as the additional ball.  For instance, you count the following distribution twice:  Anna receives a pink ball and a yellow ball, Brenda receives a red ball, Charles receives a blue ball, and Dana receives a green ball.  You count it once when you designate the pink ball as the ball Anna must receive and the yellow ball as the additional ball, and once when you designate the yellow ball as the ball Anna must receive and the pink ball as the additional ball.

Comment: Thanks for telling why my method was wrong..this was helpful.

Comment: But how did you make 5 red?

Comment: @DravitGupta I typed `$\color{red}{5}$`.

Answer (score 0):

Would a stars and bars approach be appropiate for this problem? I mean, we're placing n=5 objects (balls) into k=4 bins (children)... Just an idea

Comment: That technique is used when indistinguishable objects are placed in distinct bins.